# Bot framework user selected button text is not displaying in bot

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, botframework

I am developing Microsoft teams bot using ms bot framework. In that, i am using adaptive cards for displaying description and two buttons.

when user clicks the button, that time i need pass json data to backend. If I pass string data (**"data": "ONE"**) on button action then I can able to read the arguments in backend and user clicked button text is coming in bot. Kindly see the code and output image below

```json
{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Hi, this is your Botzer personal assistant , how can I help you? <a href=\"https://www.powerupcloud.com/blogs/\" target=\"_blank\">Click Here </a>",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "isSubtle": false,
                "wrap": true
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "ONE",
                "data": "ONE"
            },
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "TWO",
                "data": "TWO"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

But, when I send json data on button action (**"data": { "id": "action2", "name": "two", "value": "TWO"}**) that time i can read the data in backend. But, button text is not coming on the bot. Kindly see the code and output image below

```json
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Choose the number",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "isSubtle": false,
                "wrap": true
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "ONE",
                "data": {
                    "id": "action1",
                    "name": "one",
                    "value": "ONE"}
            },
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "TWO",
                "data": {
                    "id": "action2",
                    "name": "two",
                    "value": "TWO"}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This great blogpost by Kyle Delaney and the Azure Bot Service team about Adaptive Cards and Bot Framework (including Teams channel) addresses issues like the one you are facing: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a *message back*, which combines the functionality of string submit actions and object submit actions. Since you don't have any inputs in your Adaptive Card, you can replace it with a hero card and use a `messageBack` action directly. If you still want to use an Adaptive Card then you're in luck because Teams actually has special functionality that allows you to put a message back in an Adaptive Card. You can see how to do that in the "Adaptive Cards in Teams" section of the blog post Hessel linked to, or you can consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-cards-with-messageback-action) directly.

Comment: "Adaptive Cards in Teams" this section helped. Thanks a lot